# After login by creating a session data is not listed on the jsp page retrieved from the database

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have been trying to list out the data that is in a specific table in my database. The data is only retrieved when i just execute the particular servlet. It does not fetch that list when i have logged in and has created a session and is directed to that particulr jsp page. I only get an empty page.

I have tried getting the session attribute to that jsp page but it does not work

list-medicine.jsp

```
<body>
<%
if(session.getAttribute("email")==null)
{
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}
%>


<div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            Welcome ${email}
            add medicine
        </div>
    </div>

<form action="UserLogoutControllerServlet">
  <input type="submit" value="Logout">
</form>

<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Email of the user</th>
    </tr>   

    <c:forEach var="tempStudent"  items="${MEDICINE_LIST}">
    <tr>
        <td>${tempStudent.name}</td>
        <td>${tempStudent.amount}</td>
        <td>${tempStudent.price}</td>
        <td>${tempStudent.email}</td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>

    </table>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

MedicineControllerServlet.java

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try
        //list tje medicine...in MVC fashion
        {
            listMedicine(request,response);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }


    }



    private void listMedicine(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        //get medicine from db util
        List<Medicine> medicine=medicineDbUtil.getMedicine();

        //add medicne from db util
        request.setAttribute("MEDICINE_LIST", medicine);

        //send to jsp view(view)
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("/list-medicine.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }
```

MedicineDbUtil.java

```
public List<Medicine> getMedicine() throws Exception
    {
        List<Medicine> medicine=new ArrayList<>();

        Connection myConn=null;
        Statement myStmt=null;
        ResultSet myRs=null;

        try
        {
        //get a connection
        myConn = dataSource.getConnection();

        //create sql statement
        String sql="select name,amount,price,users_email from  medicine ";

        myStmt= myConn.createStatement();

        //execute query
        myRs=myStmt.executeQuery(sql);

        //process result set
        while(myRs.next())
        {

            //retrieve data from result set row
            //int id=myRs.getInt("id");
            String name=myRs.getString("name");
            int amount=myRs.getInt("amount");
            double price=myRs.getDouble("price");
            String email=myRs.getString("users_email");


            //create new medicine
            Medicine theMedicine=new Medicine(name,amount,price,email);


            //add it to list of medicine
            medicine.add(theMedicine);

        }
        return medicine;

        }finally
        {
            //close jdbc objects
            close(myConn,myStmt,myRs);
        }




    }
```

I want the data list fetched from the database to be shown in the jsp page while i am logged in through a session

Comment: We need to see the servlet code, too.

Comment: I added the servlet codes

Comment: The code looks good at the first glance, but there is no exception handling in the `getMedicine()` method - so if there is any problem reading the DB, you won't know it! Add a `catch` block with at least `exception.printStackTrace();` and watch the log.

Comment: I added the try catch block, but the thing is query is working fine. If i just execute the servlet only it shows the exact data i want. But when log in and a session is started, then the data is not shown

Comment: So you see only the table header, but no data rows, do I understand it correctly?

Comment: yes exactly that is what happens

Comment: Uhm... try `items="${request.MEDICINE_LIST}"`, although the request context should be the default one to look for attributes.

Comment: What is the URL displayed in the location bar of your browser when looking at the empty table?

Comment: http://localhost:8181/webdemo/list-medicine.jsp    -this

Comment: OK, so that's the problem. Why would anything be displayed in the table? You sent a request to the JSP directly, without going through the controller servlet which loads the data from the database, puts them in a request attribute and then forwards to the view to display that data. The principle of the MVC pattern is that you should never, ever send a request to a view. Only to a controller. The views (i.e. the JSPs) shouldn't even be accessible from the outside, and should be put under WEB-INF to ensure that.

Comment: Oops, `localhost:8181/webdemo/list-medicine.jsp` is wrong, you should see the URL of the servlet.

Comment: if(loginDbUtil.check(email, password))
  {  
   User theUser=loginDbUtil.gettype(email);

   String p="pharmacist";
  
   if(theUser.getType().equals(p))
   {
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
     session.setAttribute("email", email);
     response.sendRedirect("list-medicine.jsp");
   }
   else
   {
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
   }

Comment: so um this is my loginservlet i redirect the logger to list-medicne.jsp should i change it then?

Comment: Yes, you should change it to redirect to the URL of your **controller**, and not to the URL of your **view**.

Comment: But then i get a 404 error -The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Comment: ah i got it thank you very much